# How to check if player sign out of the google play services in unity3d

Tags: google-play-games

how do unity check if player manually sign out from the leaderboard in google play service. I am using the GPG plugin for this and my platform is in android

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit dated, but I was just looking into this and thought I'd share what I found.

When you sign out from within the leaderboard (or achievements page), the GPG plugin gives you an error that looks like this:

** [Play Games Plugin DLL]  ERROR: Authentication has been lost!

which causes PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated () to return false.

One way to find catch this is simply listening to the script that is displaying the message.  Their log function is written below. Just look at the msg arg and toggle your variable you are using to keep track of the logged in state.

```
- GooglePlayGames > OurUtils > Logger.cs
     ...
        public static void e(string msg) {
            Debug.LogWarning("*** " + LOG_PREF + " ERROR: " + msg);
            if (msg == "Authentication has been lost!") {
                // yourScript.isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        }
     ...
```

Alternatively, you could check the value of PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated() when the user attempts to access one of the GPG services (leaderboard, achievements, etc).  If it is false, the user is not signed in and should be prompted to sign in rather than firing the service.